# Better way to have two equal models but with different scope

Tags: php, laravel

I'm in laravel 10, and I need to analyse some data.

During the analisis I need to save them in a little different way (I can save them olso in the same way is not a big problem) but the logic is more or less the same.

I need to check all the data and them save them in two different tables, one every half hour, and one for the single day (max min avg values [for the daily report I need to get the datetime where I have maximum and minimum]).

For the moment I have two different models, but everytime I need to change each two models.

I can code it in a single point?? I was thinking about interface, but I olso read about laravel service provider, but I never handle them.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Let s see if I understand, you have a model like Report30minutes and Reportdaily, in two different db tables, if this is the case why not just making a Report model with a column where you specify the type?

Comment: It can be an idea, but what if tomorrow will be handle in a different way?

Comment: a quick fix could be to save the different/new part in a json column and have different php code to save and retrieve/interpret the saved payload. i believe there is never a quick perfect answer to future scenario.